# Can amorphous set and AC for finite sets coexist?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A set being amorphous means every subset of it is either finite or cofinite. AC for finite sets means any family of finite sets has a choice function, i.e. if $f:A\to I$ is surjective and for each $i\in I$, $f^{-1}(i)$ is finite, then there is $s:I\to A$ such that $fs$ is identity on $I$. Over ZF, "every set can be linearly ordered" implies that there is no amorphous set, and it also implies AC for finite sets. But can we have amorphous sets and AC for finite sets at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an elementary proof.

Proposition. If a set is amorphous then there cannot be a choice function on the set of its finite, non-empty subsets.

The proof is by contradiction. Suppose there is an amorphous set $S$ with a choice function $f$ on its finite, non-empty subsets. We define an extension of $f$ covering the infinite subsets.

Let $X$ be an infinite subset of $S$. For each $x \in X$ we define two sets

$A_x = \{y \in X \setminus \{x\} :  f(\{x,y\}) = x \}$ and $B_x = \{y \in X \setminus \{x\} :  f(\{x,y\}) = y \}$

Exactly one of these will be finite, call it $F_x$.

$A_x$ and $B_x$ can be empty, but for at most one value of $x$ each,say $a$ and $b$ respectively. If $a$ exists define $f(X) = a$. If there is no $a$ but $b$ exists, define $f(X) = b$.

Otherwise, all $F_x \neq \emptyset$ and we can define a function $g:X \rightarrow X$ by $g(x) = f(F_x)$ . Note $g(x) \neq x$ for all $x$.

Consider the sequences of the form $x, g(x), g(g(x)), \dots$ As $X$ has no denumerable subsets these must always eventually start repeating. Call the sets which contain the repeating part of such a sequence loops. Let $\mathscr L$ be the set of loops. The loops are pairwise disjoint and each is finite with at least two elements. So the sets

$\{f(L) : L \in \mathscr L\}$ and $\{g(f(L)) : L \in \mathscr L \}$

are disjoint subsets of $X$ and of the same cardinality as $\mathscr L$. Therefore there are only finitely many loops and we can define $f(X) = f(\bigcup\mathscr L)$ .

In all cases, $f(X) \in X$, so the extended $f$ is a choice function on the set of non-empty subsets of $X$. This is not possible for an amorphous set. So $f$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is shown in Truss' paper as a corollary of Theorem 3.

> *Truss, John*, [**Classes of Dedekind finite cardinals**](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-84-3-187-208), Fundam. Math. 84, 187-208 (1974). [ZBL0292.02049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0292.02049).

In short, if $X$ is amorphous, then for all $n>1$, $[X]^n$ does not admit a choice function.